# Why are the field names in the WHERE statement of a self join reversed in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, where-clause, self-join

I wrote a WHERE statement that works with column names in one order, but not in reverse order.  I don't know why and am curious if someone can explain.

The code below works.  When I had WHERE e.emp_num = m.emp_manager, the code didn't work.

```
    SELECT DECODE (e.emp_initial,null, e.emp_fname||' '|| e.emp_lname,
         e.emp_fname ||' '|| e.emp_initial ||'. '|| e.emp_lname) AS Employee,
         m.emp_fname ||' '|| m.emp_lname AS Manager
    FROM hartmar.employee e,
         hartmar.employee m
    WHERE e.emp_manager = m.emp_num
    ORDER BY e.emp_lname, e.emp_fname, e.emp_initial
```

Comment: In my output incorrect code (WHERE e.emp_num = m.emp_manager), the employee and manager columns were reversed.  When I changed that to (WHERE e.emp_manager = m.emp_num), the column for employee had employees and the column for managers had managers, as expected.

Answer (score 0):

you need to also swap the table aliases when swapping the columns..

all the columns in the SELECT list need to correspond (e.g. the Names) to the table you wish to be the manager vs the employee.

swap out all those a. up in the beginning also for correct results.